# tkinter ttk theme: _tkinter.TclError: image file format "svg" is not supported

Tags: python, tkinter, svg, themes, ttk

I tried out [this ttk theme](https://github.com/rdbende/Sun-Valley-ttk-theme-svg), that uses `svg` images. But it says image file format `svg` isn't supported.

On this line:

```py
root.tk.call('source','./DATA/themes/sun-valley-dark.tcl')
```

this error is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "guitesting.py", line 141, in <module>
    root.tk.call('source','./DATA/themes/sun-valley-dark.tcl')
_tkinter.TclError: image file format "svg" is not supported
```

Useful information:

```
OS: Windows 7
Python: Python 3.8.10
Architecture: x86 (32-bit)
Tkinter version: 8.6
```

Comment: just like the error said, tkinter didn't support `svg` format.

Comment: so how may i use this theme?

Comment: I don't know where you got this theme but when I searched for it, I found https://github.com/rdbende/Sun-Valley-ttk-theme which uses PNG files and works fine for me.

Comment: so can i use this theme by any means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install tksvg via pip: `python -m pip install tksvg`

add at the top of the file

```
import tksvg
```

And

```
tksvg.load(root)
root.tk.call('source','./DATA/themes/sun-valley-dark.tcl')
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the theme i had to install `tksvg` via pip:
`python -m pip install tksvg`

**I got the answer by @rdbende through email